# How to integrate a Frame (jframe) into a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, applet, jframe, awt

Iam New to Awt,Jframe. I have to integrate a Frame window (containg code to display a whiteboard) into a jsp page. can you please helpout in this regard
to integrate an applet iam using

```
<applet code="com.pvn.WhiteBoardMain.class" codebase="." archive="Applets.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
```

so how can i present this frame window itself in a jsp page

Comment: Launch the frame from a link using Java Web Start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an applet is a container, just add the frame. It should work.

If your applet is *myApplet* and your frame *myFrame*, the following code should work (I assume *myFrame* has been set visible first):

```
myApplet.add( myFrame );
myApplet.validate(); // to force a redraw.
```